# Java Adding Numbers Together + Score?

Tags: numbers, int

Hi I have made this to add to a score systems.

```
public int Cascore = 0;
public int Dascore = 0;
        public int dascore () {
        return Dscore = + 5;
    }
    public int cascore () {
        return Cscore = + 3;
    }
    public int ddascore () {
        return Dscore = + 1;
    }
```

I call these methods dascore() cascore() during points in the code that add to the score system but the overall Dascore and Cascore seem to just be 3 or 5.

```
 System.out.println("Bad Score: " + Dscore);
          System.out.println("Good Score: " + Cscore);
```

Just out puts 5 & 3.  When it should be something like 160/130...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try :

> Dscore **+=** 5

not **=+**

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you wanted to this instead

```
public int Cascore = 0;
public int Dascore = 0;
    public int dascore () {
        return Dscore +=  5;
    }
public int cascore () {
        return Cscore +=  3;
    }
public int ddascore () {
        return Dscore +=  1;
    }
```

Comment: Ahhh.. always the small things.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This isn't working because you aren't writing the correct code. Well, your IDE should generate an error...

There is nothing like the following in java!

```
= +
```

Java, as other language do, supports +=

Even + = is wrong too in java. Because there can't be a space between these two operators.

```
public int Cascore = 0;
public int Dascore = 0;
    public int dascore () {
    return Dscore += 5;
}
public int cascore () {
    return Cscore += 3;
}
public int ddascore () {
    return Dscore += 1;
}
```

For better understandability, Until you are using a Constant, don't start your variable name with an upper case letter.